# How can I find out which parameters a route has in php

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Background:
I want to alter a self written Twig extension.
The class is defined as follows:

```
class pagination extends \Twig_Extension { 
    protected $generator;

    public function __construct($generator){
        $this->generator = $generator;
    }

    ....
}
```

In one of the methods i want to generate an URL like this:

```
$this->generator->generate($route, array('routeParam' => $value);
```

But the problem is, that some routes don't have the param 'routeParam' whichg would cause an Exception when generating the route this way.

My question is: How can i find out if a given route has certain paramters in that method?

Comment: If you generate a URL using your example for a route that doesn't require the parameter it should just add it in the `$_GET` string like `/your/url?routeParam=value`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To check your route has all the params you need to compile your route , to compile route you need router service so pass `@service_container` service to your twig extension by adding in your service definition

```
somename.twig.pagination_extension:
    class: Yournamesapce\YourBundle\Twig\Pagination
    arguments: [ '@your_generator_service','@service_container'  ]
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension } ...
```

And in your class get container then get router service from container and get all routes by `getRouteCollection()` once you have all routes get the desired route fro collection by `$routes->get($route)` then compile that route,once your have a complied route definition you can get all the params required for route by calling `getVariables()` which will return array of parameters and before generating check in array if `routeParam` exists

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface as Container;
class Pagination extends \Twig_Extension { 
    protected $generator;
    private $container;
    public function __construct($generator,Container $container){
        $this->generator = $generator;
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function somefunction(){
        $routes = $this->container->get('router')->getRouteCollection();
        $routeDefinition = $routes->get($route);
        $compiledRoute = $routeDefinition->compile();
        $all_params = $compiledRoute->getVariables();
        if(in_array('routeParam',$all_params)){
            $this->generator->generate($route, array('routeParam' => $value);
        }
    }
    ....
}
```